# How to fix ressources locations conflicts (CSS,JS,IMG) due to URL Rewriting and navbar links?

Tags: css, url, href, conflict, rewriting

Ok, there are already some topics about the general subject but I'm concerned by a situation I can't find in the already existing topics so sorry if I may have missed the exact same topic than the current one you're reading (if you have a link why not).

**Situation :**
I did URL rewriting, all is good, when I enter in URL " mywebsite/general/home" it does the whole treating in my controller and includes view perfectly.
The thing is that in my navbar view, the href are in this form "general/home" and so,  when I'm already on home page, if I click this nav link, the localhost server is looking for something like "mywebsite/general/home/general/home" (or even sometimes "mywebsite/general/general/home").
Consequently the nav links href are messed as the server think "general" and "home" are true physical folders.

I've tried many solution like `<base href="">` or `<base href="mywebsite/">` or `<base href="/mywebsite">` or even `<base href="http://localhost/fullpath/mywebsite/">` but it still doesn't work, messing with the URL arguments and ending up never finding ressources to display views correctly (or even basically navigation between pages).

***Thanks a lot if you can be of any kind of help for this frustrating problem !***

N.B. : Defining `<base href="whateverinside">` is really problematic when it comes to href="#!" in navbar as I have some of these that when clicked on, they open dropdown menus and so because of this href base, the page refreshes even on fake links making dropdown menu unusable...

Comment: **Update** : I have no more conflicts about searching location of CSS and all... BUT to do this, I had to include absolute path (http://localhost/etcetc...) in the right part of RewriteRules, in the .htaccess...

The problem ? For some reason, I don't know why yet, the URL rewrite no longer do its job. The href="general/home" in another page works fine but the URL I end up with always goes back to "mywebsite/index.php?param1=general&param2=home".

To be continued...

Comment: **Update 2** : I've tried to just upload the website online and suddenly, URL rewriting with .htaccess becomes way easier. Everything is working fine and I just had to put a slash before all the "index.php?blahblahblah..." in the RewriteRules.
The only thing I need to not forget is that when I create a href link in views, I have to put a slash at beginning of the link, allowing me links like this "/general/home".